# Convergence to $\mu$ in $L^{2}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of random variables on the same probability space.

$\mathbb E(X_{l})=\mu$ for any $l$.

We have weak correlation: $\mathrm{Cov}(X_{k},X_{l})\leq f(|k-l|)$ for all indexes $k$, $l$, where the sequence $(f(m))_{m\geq 0}$ converges to $0$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$.

I'm trying to prove that $\displaystyle (n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k})_{n\geq 1}$ converges to $\mu$ in $L^{2}$.

---

A sequence $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of random variables, with $\mathbb E(X_{n}^2)_{n\geq  1}<\infty$, converges in the $L^2$- norm to a random variable $X$ with $\mathbb E (X^2)<\infty$ if:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb E\left(X_n-X\right)^2=0$$

So this means that I'm trying to show:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb E\left(\displaystyle (n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k})_{n\geq 1}-\mu\right)^2=0$$

Without loss of generality (since we can replace $X_i$ with $X_i-\mu$) let $\mu=0$ and square:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb E\left[\displaystyle \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}\right)^2\right]=0$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb E\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}\right)^2=0$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb E\sum_{k,l=1}^{n}X_{k}X_{l}=0$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k,l=1}^{n}\mathbb E[X_{k}X_{l}]=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k,l=1}^{n}\mathrm{Cov}(X_{k},X_{l})=0$$

How do I use the weak correlation? Are there any theorems or tricks that are relevant here? Thanks!

Comment: Try expanding the square.  It's a little cleaner to work with the case $\mu = 0$, which loses no generality because you can replace $X_i$ by $X_i - \mu$.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this. Would you mind telling me what to try now?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\left( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \right)^2 = \sum_{k,l=1}^n X_k X_l.$$
(This is what I meant by "expand the square".)  Thus, when $\mu = 0$, 
$$\mathbb{E}\left( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \right)^2 = \sum_{k,l=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_k X_l] = \sum_{k,l=1}^n \operatorname{Cov}(X_k, X_l).$$